# QML Change list data role within ListModel

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I try to update nested list data of list elements within a list model:

```
Item {

  width: 400
  height: 300

  ListModel {
    id: myModel
    ListElement {
       name: "Banana"
       myId: "1.95"
       attributes: [
          ListElement { event: "Tropical" }
       ]
     }

  }

  MouseArea {
     anchors.fill: parent
     onClicked: {
        myModel.setProperty(0, "attributes", {"event" : "testNEW"}); 
        //myModel.setProperty(0, "attributes", [{"event" : "testNEW"}]); 
     }
  }

  ListView {
     anchors.fill: parent

     model: myModel
     delegate: Item {
        height: 50
        width: 100
        Repeater {
            model: attributes
            Text { text: event }
        }
     }
  }

  Component.onCompleted: {
    myModel.append{"name" : "name", "myId" : "2.23", "attributes" : [{"event" : "test"}];    
  }    
}
```

The problem is that the code above did not update the `attributes` property.

The only way how to update the property was using following code:

`myModel.get(0).attributes.get(0).event = "testNEW"`

**Question**

How to update the `attributes` property with `setProperty`?

Comment: Hmm ... did you test your code before posting here? What does `id: 1.95` mean? The line with `myModel.append` contains at least 3 errors. Please correct it.

Comment: Ohh...sry. Mixed up some stuff when writing the code directly here. Should be fixed now.